# Difference between these two propositions about y>x for integers y and x?

Tags: logic

What is the difference between the two propositions in the attached image? How is the order in which the first two parentheses are presented relevant? The notes to these say the first is true and the second is false. My current understanding is that the first expression says, "for all integers x, there exists an integer y which is greater than x". This seems counter-intuitive to me- if we consider all of the integers, represented by x, how can there be a larger integer than all of these, as wouldn't this larger integer be considered as one of the values of x in the first place as we consider x to be all of the integers? I therefore assume that this is not the correct interpretation of proposition 1. I would appreciate an explanation as to these matters.

[image]

Comment: The quantifier order matters! Classic question. In the first, ask "Can I always find a integer bigger than a given one?" In the second, "Is there an integer bigger than all other integers?"

Comment: @SeanRoberson thanks- does this mean that in the first statement, we first select an x from the set of all integers, and then ask whether there is a y greater than this, and then abstract this process for all values of x? Does that mean in the second, we select the y before we consider the values of x, and then try to abstract this process for all y's  well? I am confused as to when we would select a value from a set rather than consider all of the values at once.